# GroovyScriptEngine fails to load imports of running groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

**Background :**

*I started playing with Groovy recently and am trying to embed a groovy script engine in an eclipse plugin to let my customers develop their own GUI extensions inside my eclipse-based product. This is very similar to the [success story](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Integrating+Groovy+in+an+application+-+a+success+story) published on codehaus's website.*

**Problem**

The groovy script (let's call it "main_eclipse.groovy") run from the eclipse plugin by a GroovyScriptEngine throws when trying to load a groovy class ("SwtGuiBuilder"), with the following error :

> BUG! Queuing new source whilst already iterating. Queued source is 'file:/home/nicolas/workspace/groovy-test/src/gui/SwtGuiBuilder.groovy'

**Question**

Did anyone run into the same problem ? How can it be fixed ?
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Some observations :

- When using the groovy interpreter instead of a GroovyScriptEngine java object, I have no problem using my SwtGuiBuilder class (see script "main_groovy" here below).
- My problem does not seem to be a classpath issue, since the file containing my SwtGuiBuilder class is mentioned in the thrown exception.
- The error message is mentioned in two reported groovy bugs, GRECLIPSE-429 and GRECLIPSE-1037. I did not fully get the technicals details, but those bugs seemed to be related to performance issues when loading lots of classes, which is not relevant in my situation...

**Details**

*SampleView.java*

```
public class SampleView
{
public SampleView() { super(); }

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 
{
    String    groovyScript = null;
    String [] groovyPath   = null;

    boolean shall_exit = false;
    do
    {      // ask user for params
        GroovyLocationDialog groovyLocationDialog= new GroovyLocationDialog(parent.getShell() );
        int return_code = groovyLocationDialog.open();
        if ( return_code != Window.OK )
            shall_exit = true;
        else 
        {
            groovyScript= groovyLocationDialog.getInputScriptName();
            groovyPath  = groovyLocationDialog.getInputScriptPath();

            // run it
            ScriptConnector scriptConnector = new ScriptConnector(parent);
            try                 { scriptConnector.runGuiComponentScript( groovyPath, groovyScript); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println("script finished");
        }
    }
    while ( ! shall_exit );
}
```

*ScriptConnector.java*

```
public class ScriptConnector
{
    private String[]  roots;
    private Composite window;
    private Binding   binding;

    public ScriptConnector( Composite window )
    {
         this.window    = window;
         Binding  scriptenv = new Binding();    // A new Binding is created ...
         scriptenv.setVariable("SDE", this); 
         scriptenv.setVariable("WINDOW", this.window); // ref to current window

         this.binding = scriptenv;
    }

    public void runGuiComponentScript(final String[] groovyPath, final String scriptName) 
    {
        GroovyScriptEngine gse = null;
        this.roots     = groovyPath;
        try 
        {
            // instanciating the script engine with current classpath
            gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( roots, this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
            gse.run(scriptName, binding);      // ... and run specified script
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

*main_eclipse.groovy*

```
package launcher;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout as Layout

// This import will fail...
import gui.SwtGuiBuilder;


WINDOW.layout = new Layout(SWT.VERTICAL);
def builder = new SwtGuiBuilder(WINDOW);
builder.Label ( style=SWT.NONE, text = 'Simple demo of Groovy and SWT')
builder.Button( style=SWT.PUSH, text = 'Click me' , action = { println "Click !" } )
```

*SwtGuiBuilder.groovy*

```
package gui;

import org.eclipse.swt.events.*
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label


class SwtGuiBuilder
{
    private Composite _parent

    public SwtGuiBuilder(Composite parent) { _parent = parent }

    public void Button( style = SWT.PUSH, text= null, action = null )
    {
        def btn = new Button(_parent, style)
        if ( text != null )
            btn.text = text
        if (action != null)
            btn.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() { void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) { action(); } } );
    }

    public void Label( style = SWT.NONE, text = '' )
    {
        def lbl = new Label(_parent, style)
        lbl.text = text
    }
}
```

*main_groovy.groovy*

```
package launcher;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout as Layout

// ... But this import is handled properly !
import gui.SwtGuiBuilder;

def display = new Display()
def WINDOW = new Shell(display)
WINDOW.text = 'Groovy / SWT Test';

WINDOW.layout = new Layout(SWT.VERTICAL);
def builder = new SwtGuiBuilder(WINDOW);
builder.Label ( style=SWT.NONE, text = 'Simple demo of Groovy and SWT')
builder.Button( style=SWT.PUSH, text = 'Click me' , action = { println "Ya clicked me !" } )

WINDOW.pack();
WINDOW.open();

while (!WINDOW.disposed) {
    if (!WINDOW.display.readAndDispatch())
        WINDOW.display.sleep();
}
```

*Stack trace*

BUG! Queuing new source whilst already iterating.  Queued source is 'file:/home/nicolas/workspace/groovy-test/src/gui/SwtGuiBuilder.groovy'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.addSource(CompilationUnit.java:460)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.addSource(CompilationUnit.java:433)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader$3.findClassNode(GroovyScriptEngine.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:863)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:377)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1407)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:202)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:713)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:1015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:647)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:596)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:247)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:229)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:244)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:202)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.loadScriptByName(GroovyScriptEngine.java:514)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.createScript(GroovyScriptEngine.java:564)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine.run(GroovyScriptEngine.java:551)

My configuration :

- Linux Ubuntu 14.04 x86
- Groovy Version: 2.3.2
- JVM: 1.7.0_55
- Eclipse Kepler SR2 - Build 20140224-0627
- Eclipse Groovy plugin v2.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GroovyScriptEngine, I've used the GroovyShell class (groovy code below but easy enough to change back to java), CompilerConfiguration allows you to specify the classpath.

```
    def config = new CompilerConfiguration(classpath: classpath)
    def binding = new Binding()

    def result = new GroovyShell(binding, config).evaluate("""
def foo='bar'
""")
```